# Determine a winner with if / else

Tags: javascript, console, operators

Can anyone help me out and explain to me how I can use operators inside an if / else statement, I am trying to do something simple and get a result of two different multiplications, I'm a self taught developer so please bear with me

```js
var oscar = {
  height: 155,
  age: 22,
};
var andrew = {
  height: 170,
  age: 16,
};

if ((oscar * 5) > (andrew * 5)) {
  console.log('Oscar is the winner');
} else if ((oscar * 5) < (andrew * 5)) {
  console.log('Andrew is the winner')
} else {
  console.log('No winner')
}
```

Comment: `oscar` and `andrew` are *object*s, not numbers. What are you trying to do? You can't multiply objects together like that.

Comment: Also no need to multiply by anything if you multiply both sides of the equal sign with the same number

Comment: I am trying to multiply the objects with 5 to determine who has the bigger result to console.log a winner, what am I doing wrong here

Comment: If you are looking to compare the individual age or height then you need to do oscar.age===andrew.age. As they are objects you need to first mention the object name and then the property. This is called dot notation.

Comment: But objects aren't numbers, so "multiply the objects" doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to compare a particular *property* of the objects?

Comment: Also, why multiply both by 5, even if you are trying to comare height or age? By definition it won't matter `x*5 > y*5` will yield the EXACT same result as `x > y`.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are objects, you must specify the property of comparison.
No need to multiply by 5.

```js
var oscar = {
  height: 155,
  age: 22
};
var andrew = {
  height: 170,
  age: 16
};

if ((oscar.height) > (andrew.height)) {
  console.log('Oscar is the winner');
} else if ((oscar.height) < (andrew.height)) {
  console.log('Andrew is the winner')
} else {
  console.log('No winner')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare objects like that.

Perhaps you wanted to assign some points? Then add another property which you CAN calculate on

Also no need to multiply by anything if you multiply both sides of the equal sign with the same number

You could do this:

```js
function scoreIt(p1,p2) {

  var diff = p1.points - p2.points;
  console.log("diff", diff);

  if (diff > 0) {
    console.log(p1.name+ ' is the winner with ' + p1.points);
  } else if (diff < 0) {
    console.log(p2.name + ' is the winner with ' + p2.points);
  } else {
    console.log('No winner - tied score ' + p1.points);
  }
}

var participant1 = {
  name: "Oscar",
  height: 155,
  age: 22,
  points: 8 // no trailing comma
};
var participant2 = {
  name: "Andrew",
  height: 170,
  age: 16 // no trailing comma
};

// later somewhere:
participant2.points = 9; // assignment
scoreIt(participant1,participant2);

participant1.points += 5; // increase
scoreIt(participant1,participant2);

participant2.points += 4;
scoreIt(participant1,participant2);
```

The object would be even better if you use the names as keys:

```
var participants = {
  "Oscar": {
    height: 155,
    age: 22,
    points: 8 // no trailing comma
  },
  "Andrew" : {
    height: 170,
    age: 16 // no trailing comma
  }
}
```